# Can I vote in the primary for one party and then vote for the other in the general?

Tags: united-states, election, parties, president, primaries

Let's say there are 3 candidates (1, 2, 3) and two parties (A, B).

Candidate 1: is good and is in party A

Candidate 2: is OK but is in party B

Candidate 3: is horrible and in party A

If you vote for candidate 1 and they don't get the nomination are you obligated to vote for candidate 3? Or can you vote for the other party in the general election?

I want to support the person I like but I also don't want to get stuck.

Comment: How would anyone ever know how you voted in the general?

Comment: I am almost certain we had an identical question recently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes

There are no limits on your vote in the general based on the primary.  You could vote for candidate 1 in the primary and vote for any of the three candidates in the general.  You can even vote for candidate 2 over candidate 1 despite having already voted for candidate 1.

The only thing that you generally can't do is vote in both primaries.  You generally have to pick one or the other.

Another way of saying this is that even if you register in party A so as to vote for candidate 1 in the primary, you can still vote for candidate 2 in the general.  Primaries are the only elections where party registration matters.